# Instruments makes app crash when setting image property of UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad, instruments

I'm having some trouble with Instruments. My app is working perfectly without crashes, but I would like to check for memory leaks with Instruments. Only problem is, Instruments makes the app crash at the same spot every time -- never crashes without Instruments.

I have pin-pointed the exact line which makes the app crash. When I comment it out, the app does not crash.

This is the line that is causing trouble for Instruments:

```
self.speakerImageView.image = image;
```

speakerImageView is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *speakerImageView;
```

image is a valid UIImage object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is `self.speakerImageView` a valid object (not nil or a released object)  by the time you call `self.speakerImageView.image = image;`?

Comment: Instruments via simulator or via device?

Comment: Via simulator. Won't even run via device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using image named? The reasing I'm asking is because using imagenamed causes a crash. Do not use image named and give it another try.

Comment: No, I'm actually using imageWithData:

Comment: try with speakerImageView.image = image;  instead    self.speakerImageView.image = image;

Comment: amazingly, that did the trick! Could you explain that to me??